# SharePoint 2019 Relevant Documents Web Part throwing "...exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator"

Tags: sharepoint-server, web-part, error, 2019

I'm pretty new the SharePoint scene and have just started a new job where I've been asked to take up some of the support. The site is using the "Relevant Documents" web part and is displaying the following error: "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold enforced by the administrator."

**Background**:

- SharePoint 2019 (on-premises)
- "Classic" view (as some legacy features are required by the business)
- about 70 libraries on the site
- largest library: ~6500 items
- total items for libraries: ~33,500
- List View Threshold = 30,000

We have a site page that uses the "Relevant Documents" web part with the following Data properties set:

- "Include documents last modified by me" : **checked**
- "Display a link to the containing folder or list" : **checked**
- "Maximum number of items shown (between 1 and 10,000)." : **10**

**Investigation**

I've determined that the web part query triggers the threshold error since it queries across all the document libraries in the site which have more than 30000 items combined.

Most posts regarding the threshold error recommend adding indexes and creating views using those indexes. Since the "Relevant Documents" web part queries across all the document libraries in the site, I don't think this is a viable solution, or at the very least a huge amount of work. Other posts recommend increasing the List View Threshold.

Has anyone encountered the issue with this "Relevant Documents" web part?  If so, were you able to resolve the issue and how did you resolve it?  Or any recommendations of a different method to retrieve a list of links to the top n recently modified documents by the current user?

Thank you.

Cheers,
Andy

Comment: Have you considered using search web parts instead? You could have complicated queries and it would be far more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Callum Crowley - looking into it now.

Comment: Hi @CallumCrowley - I had to put this down for a while. I tried adding and configuring a CSWP, but it's not displaying the correct results.  Do you happen to know of a good resource for CSWP query building?  Thanks!